# Scrapy with LinkExtractor not extracting links from a website

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl a website to output the all the links from a particular link, using the LinkExtractor function.

Scrapy is not outputting the links for some websites. For example, if I try this link https://blog.nus.edu.sg, it seems to work. But not for http://nus.edu.sg

All these links yield a working website. I have tried to look at the source code of both sites, and both look similar in terms of how they link to other sites

This is my crawler

```
class Crawler(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'all'

    def __init__(self, startURL):
        self.links=[]
        self.start_urls = [startURL]

    custom_settings = {
        'LOG_LEVEL': logging.WARNING,
        'DEPTH_LEVEL': 1
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        le = LinkExtractor()
        print(le)
        for link in le.extract_links(response):
            print(link.url)
```

where it is called using the following function

```
def _getLinksDriver(url):


    header = {'USER_AGENT': agent} #agent is some user agent previously defined
    process = CrawlerProcess(header)
    process.crawl(Crawler, url)

    process.start(stop_after_crawl=True)
```

For example, if I tried 
`_getLinksDriver("http://nus.edu.sg")`

The output is simply

```
2019-06-11 11:42:22 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.6.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2019-06-11 11:42:22 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.3.3.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 19.2.0, Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) - [GCC 8.2.0], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019), cryptography 2.6.1, Platform Linux-4.18.0-21-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
2019-06-11 11:42:22 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'LOG_LEVEL': 30, 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'}
<scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml.LxmlLinkExtractor object at 0x7fc45fbbac18>
```

However, if we navigate to the actual site, there are clearly links to link to.

Trying `_getLinksDriver("https://blog.nus.edu.sg")` gives

```
2019-06-11 11:38:20 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.6.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2019-06-11 11:38:20 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.3.3.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 19.2.0, Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) - [GCC 8.2.0], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019), cryptography 2.6.1, Platform Linux-4.18.0-21-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
2019-06-11 11:38:20 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'LOG_LEVEL': 30, 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'}
<scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml.LxmlLinkExtractor object at 0x7fc4605bcb38>
https://blog.nus.edu.sg#main
https://blog.nus.edu.sg/
http://blog.nus.edu.sg/
https://wiki.nus.edu.sg/display/cit/Blog.nus+Common+Queries
http://help.edublogs.org/user-guide/
https://wiki.nus.edu.sg/display/cit/Blog.nus+Terms+of+Use
https://wiki.nus.edu.sg/display/cit/Blog.nus+Disclaimers
https://blog.nus.edu.sg/wp-signup.php
http://twitter.com/nuscit
http://facebook.com/nuscit
https://blog.nus.edu.sg#scroll-top
http://cyberchimps.com/responsive-theme/
http://wordpress.org/
http://cit.nus.edu.sg/
http://www.nus.edu.sg/
http://www.statcounter.com/wordpress.org/
https://blog.nus.edu.sg#wp-toolbar
https://blog.nus.edu.sg/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.nus.edu.sg%2F
```

which is what I hope to see.

How do I make this work for all websites?

Thanks

If it helps, my version of Scrapy, Python and all its dependencies

```
2019-06-11 11:42:12 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.6.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2019-06-11 11:42:12 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.3.3.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 19.2.0, Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) - [GCC 8.2.0], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019), cryptography 2.6.1, Platform Linux-4.18.0-21-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple reason why you code doesn't work for above website (`http://nus.edu.sg/`) is [Incapsula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incapsula).

If you check `response.body` you'll find something like this:

```
Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 432001820008199878-98367043303115621
```

Answer (score 1):

just an addon to gangabass answer (so pls **accept his**):

as gangabass mentioned http://nus.edu.sg is protected against bots by Incapsula.
What scrapy gets is this (`curl 'http://nus.edu.sg/'`):

```
<html>
<head>
<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow">
<script src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=5074a744e2e3d891814e9a2dace20bd4,719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3">
</script>
<body>
</body></html>
```

The actual content is loaded via javascript (which scrapy doesn't execute). If you want to execute javascript you can use scrapy-splash:
https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash

Unfortunately this is more complicated (But this is exactly what the owner of the website wants). If you want to be friendly, you don't crawl those pages (https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/08/25/how-to-crawl-the-web-politely-with-scrapy)